# menu hover and block

Tags: html, css, hover

Usually, making a  a block, you just have to hover on the `<li>` to highlight.. not on the text...

i *think* a have done it right... but only hovering on the TEXT make the text change color... hovering on the box (li) dont...

i have not taken the good technique, or just screw somewhere, i need your pointer please

thanks in advance

[here is the page](http://benoitjacquesdesigner.com/architecture_touristique2.html)

Comment: Seems to be working on FF. Which browser is causing the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Pretty simple:**

Remove the padding declarations from `#menulistbox li` by removing these lines.

```
padding-top: 5px;
padding-right: 0px;
padding-bottom: 5px;
padding-left: 5px;
```

Then add this definition for the link

```
#menulistbox li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 0 5px 5px;
}
```

**That's it :)**

P.S. Check out [CSS Shorthand Syntax](http://www.dustindiaz.com/css-shorthand/) to make your life easier and your code tidier :)